# What is the difference between onTabSelected() and onTabReselected()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an app where creating tabs using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. When first time the tabs will be loaded by default the 1st tab will be selected. But after switch to another tab when user will return on the first tab again it will check some data in database and based on the data it will show content on first tab. So I am not sure where I should call the function to check in database? `onTabSelected()` or `onTabReselected()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> onTabReselected : Called when a tab that is already selected is chosen
>   again by the user. Some applications **may use this action to return
>   to the top level of a category.**

and

> onTabSelected : is called when a tab enters the selected state (it's
>   previous state was unselected).

you should just keep a member variable as a counter and in onTabSelected when the specified tab is selected the second time do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`onTabSelected()` is when you select a tab, but it is not selected yet.

`onTabReselected()` means that the tab has already been selected and has been selected again.

In most cases, you want `onTabSelected()`. `onTabReselected()` is something like a double-click, which might be useful if you're low on screen space and want to use it as a back/refresh button or something.